# pass a javascript dictionary to an ASP.NET MVC action on controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, dictionary

From javascript I am trying to pass a dictionary to an ASP.NET MVC action in controller but it does not work. Action in controller receives an empty dictionary with no elements.

**javascript code**:

```
    var myDict = {};
    stringArray.forEach(function (key, index) { myDict[key] = booleanArray[index] });

    var actionUrl = '@Url.Action("UpdateFromDictionary", "MyController")';

    $.ajax({
        url: actionUrl,
        type: "POST",
        traditional: true,            
        data: { myDictArg: myDict },
        success: function () {
        }
    });
```

**ASP.NET MVC controller action**:

```
    public void UpdateFromDictionary(Dictionary<string, bool> myDictArg)
    {
       // Do something with dictionary
    }
```

Comment: do you consider changing the action parameter to accept JSON?

Comment: @JerdineSabio Sorry I do not understand you. I am bit new on it.... Could you post an example?

Comment: Did you forget to put `[HttpPost]` on the controller action?

Comment: just remove "traditional: true,"

Answer (score 0):

I just removed the "traditional:true,"

```
var booleanArray = ["This", "is", "a", "string"];
var myDict = {};
booleanArray.forEach(function (key, index) {
    myDict[key] = (key.length > 2)
});
debugger;
var actionUrl = '@Url.Action("UpdateFromDictionary", "Home")';

$.ajax({
    url: actionUrl,
    type: "POST",
    data: { myDictArg: myDict },
    success: function () {
    }
});
```

And I got the value 
[image]